# I don't want to focusout if user is focused on particular div

Tags: jquery, focus, focusout

I'm using focusin() function to append div dynamically below the input box which is being focused. Now when user focusout I remove that dynamically appended div, but the problem is I want to prevent that div from removing itself if user focus on that div.

My code:

```js
$('.ok').focusin(function() {
  $('.ok').after('<div class="thisdiv" tabindex="1">Okay Okay Okay</div>');
});

$('.ok').focusout(function() {
  if (!$('.thisdiv').is(':focus')) {
    $('.thisdiv').remove();
  }
});
```

```css
.thisdiv {
  background: red;
  border: 2px dashed;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 50px;
}
.thisdiv:hover,
.thisdiv:active,
.thisdiv:focus {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="ok">
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hq5dy61j/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an event handler to the dynamic div that can prevent the focus from changing when that div is clicked. This will not help when focus is changed by pressing TAB, which may or may not be desirable.

One effect of this is that the text in the dynamic div cannot be selected with a mouse. If you want this behavior, you might want to think about switching to a class based solution which gives you more control over state changes.

```js
$('.ok').focusin(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    $div = $('<div class="thisdiv" >Okay Okay Okay</div>');

  $div.on('mousedown', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
  });
  $this.after($div);
});

$('.ok').focusout(function() {
    $('.thisdiv').remove();
});
```

```css
.thisdiv {
  background: red;
  border: 2px dashed;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 50px;
}
.thisdiv:hover,
.thisdiv:active,
.thisdiv:focus {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="ok">
```

Comment: You're right, I'm now using class based solution. Thank you.